# woocommerce, авторизация по нескольким полям

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, валидация

как сделать проверку при авторизации в woocomerce  "checkout" не только по Логину или почте но что бы проверка проходила еще допустим по фамилии.

Если фамилия и логин не совпадает то выдавало бы что фамилия не связанна с данным e-mail.

Comment: Авторизация в ВП итак происходит по 2м составляющим: логину/емейлу И паролю.

Comment: да но нужно сделать еще проверку и по фамилии

Comment: Это глупо и ненужно. Логин/почта уникальные данные. Однозначно идентифицируют пользователя.

Comment: Мне нужно по мимо логина и почта еще и фамилии

Comment: Зачем "нужно"? "Шоб було"? Или ты не понимаешь, что такое уникальные данные? Более того - фамилия, **в отличии от логина и почты** НЕ УНИКАЛЬНОЕ значение.